# how do we plot a scatter plot for time in python

Tags: python, pandas, time, seaborn, scatter-plot

i want to plot a scatter plot between mentioned two columns k and s . k should be on x axis showing time on hourly basis for 24 hours and s should be on y axis. i have already tried some code using using sns.relplot but got attribute error.

[data columns in which we want scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I0Kn.png)

[**code which we tried with error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxu9Y.png)

Comment: try `sns.relplot(data=data,x='x',y='y')` (remove the apostrophe around `data`)

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2020-05-26 06:15:07','105'], ['2020-05-26 06:15:07','41'], ['2020-05-26 06:16:51','95']], columns=["k", "s"]) 
df.k = pd.to_datetime(df.k, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ax = sns.scatterplot(df.k, df.s)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=45)
ax.plot()
```

---

[image]

---

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame([['2020-05-26 06:15:07','105'], ['2020-05-26 06:15:07','41'], ['2020-05-26 06:16:51','95']], columns=["k", "s"]) 
df.k = pd.to_datetime(df.k, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df.set_index(['k'],inplace=True)
ax = sns.scatterplot(df.index, df.s)
# ax.set(xlabel="time", ylabel="values")
ax.set_xlim(df.index[0], df.index[-1])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=45)
ax.plot()
```

---

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot ...i am tryin to get 24 hours of the day on x axis like 0,1,2,3.....24 is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Using mdates

Comment: @pygril can you help me out .. i dont want the dates on x axis just the time from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59

Comment: Actually I don't have your dataset. But I feel `mdates.DayLocator()` will do in `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator` along with `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S"))`

Comment: Using the above those two. You will able to do it.

Comment: @Pygril i am uploaded snapshot of data with the new post ,,can u help?